# ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'A' using OrdinalEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
label_encode_dict['cat116']
# output
OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-99)

label_encode_dict['cat116'].transform(np.array([xq['cat116']]).reshape(-1,1))
```

**stack trace**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in _encode(values, uniques, check_unknown)
    177         try:
--> 178             return _map_to_integer(values, uniques)
    179         except KeyError as e:

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in _map_to_integer(values, uniques)
    122     table = _nandict({val: i for i, val in enumerate(uniques)})
--> 123     return np.array([table[v] for v in values])
    124 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    122     table = _nandict({val: i for i, val in enumerate(uniques)})
--> 123     return np.array([table[v] for v in values])
    124 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in __missing__(self, key)
    116             return self.nan_value
--> 117         raise KeyError(key)
    118 

KeyError: 'A'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-25237eb44032> in <module>()
----> 1 label_encode_dict['cat116'].transform(np.array([xq['cat116']]).reshape(-1,1))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in transform(self, X)
    785             Transformed input.
    786         """
--> 787         X_int, X_mask = self._transform(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)
    788         X_trans = X_int.astype(self.dtype, copy=False)
    789 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in _transform(self, X, handle_unknown, force_all_finite)
    152             # already called above.
    153             X_int[:, i] = _encode(Xi, uniques=self.categories_[i],
--> 154                                   check_unknown=False)
    155 
    156         return X_int, X_mask

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in _encode(values, uniques, check_unknown)
    178             return _map_to_integer(values, uniques)
    179         except KeyError as e:
--> 180             raise ValueError(f"y contains previously unseen labels: {str(e)}")
    181     else:
    182         if check_unknown:

ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'A'
```

Why this unseen label error came as  handle_unknown is already specified in Ordinal Encoder.

*Sk learn version = 0.24.1*

**Edited: short example **

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown = 'use_encoded_value', unknown_value = -9)
PP = [['AA','B']]
enc.fit(PP)

print(enc.categories_)

enc.transform(np.array(['A','B']).reshape(1,-1))  # gives the same  ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'A'

enc.transform(np.array(['AC','B']).reshape(1,-1))  # this works as expected
```

I am now thinking that it handles unkown_values higher than alphabetical order. In above example as 'A' is smaller than 'AA'. It resulted in error. Any turnaround for this?

Comment: Please  format traces as code, not text (edited).

Comment: There is a Issue opened in sk-learn github repo.
[link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19677)
It will be fixed in next release.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't fit the ordinal encoder, it doesn't know how to transform the data.

```
enc = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-99)
enc.fit(label_encode_dict['cat116'])
enc.transform(np.array([xq['cat116']])
```

Comment: Sorry there. But it was fitted on train data before.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. The encoder can only transform values it has already seen. It creates kind of a map with 2 lists. The first list is a string, the second list is the transformed value. So if your training data didn't have the string 'A' in it, then it won't be able to transform it because it doesn't have a mapping for it.

Comment: yes , that is why i have use the handle_unkown parameter. It is expected to handle the values not seen in the training.